# Verilog : A task with continuous assign output for local variables

Tags: task, verilog

I'm looking for  a statement ( like task/function) witch has the ability to continuous assign the output (of local variable ), not once , at the end of task .
   For example :

```
reg [7:0] out_from_task1             ;
reg [7:0] out_from_task2             ;

task automatic test   ;                                     

input  [7:0] input_task       ;
output [7:0] output_task      ;
begin 
    output_task  = 'b0                                 ;
#4  output_task = input_task                          ;
#2  output_task = input_task +2                       ;
end 
endtask

initial begin
  fork
    test(8'd10,out_from_task1)  ;
    test(8'd8,out_from_task2)  ;
  join
end
```

The value I get is the last , then **out_from_task1** has the value of 12  . I need to see the signal **out_from_task1** changes . First 10 , after a while 12 .

Can i do this without using globals variables in Verilog ?
It all started from doing more tasks in parallel in the testbench .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Verilog, `input` arguments to a task are copied by value upon entry to the task, and `output` arguments get copied upon exit to the task. Nothing gets transferred through the arguments while the task consumes time. SystemVerilog adds a `ref` argument direction which means the argument gets passed as a reference. That allows activity with the argument to be seen while the task is active:

```
task test(input [7:0] input_task, ref logic [7:0] output_task);
```

Answer (score 1):

nope, you cannot do it in verilog. The 'task' must run to the end before assigning the the output argument. As a result, in verilog you can only do it with global variables.

If you want to switch to system verilog, then you can use the `ref` argument to the task. It should work;

```
task test(input [7:0] input_task, ref [7:0] output_task);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reply from the original poster. However the proposed solution doesn't work for me. At least not with cadence incisive v15.20. `out_from_task1/2` are never driven.

Should this be be a well supported feature?

```
module tb();
 reg [7:0] out_from_task1;
 reg [7:0] out_from_task2;

 task automatic test;                                    
   input  [7:0] input_task;
   ref logic [7:0] output_task;
 begin 
     output_task  = 'b0;
 #4  output_task = input_task;
 #2  output_task = input_task +2;
     $display(input_task," ",output_task);
 end 
 endtask

 initial begin
   fork
     test(8'd10,out_from_task1);
     test(8'd8,out_from_task2);
   join
 end
endmodule
```

Comment: To elaborate simvision shows out_from_task1/2 are always x. However if I add `$display(out_from_task1)` at the end of the initial block the value is correct i.e. 12. So somehow waveforms didn't get the update that the signal was changed in the task... maybe it's a bug.